# fixed points in Z3

Tags: z3, datalog

Can someone kindly point out why the final query doesn't have output?

Basically I tell Z3 if vs-)vd and vs->ss and vd->sd, then sd is derived from ss.

```
(set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)
(define-sort site () (_ BitVec 3))

(declare-rel pointsto (Int site))
(declare-rel dcall (Int Int))
(declare-rel derived (site site))

(declare-var vs Int)
(declare-var vd Int)
(declare-var ss site)
(declare-var sd site)

;;;;; definition of derived ;;
(rule (=> (and (dcall vs vd) (pointsto vs ss) (pointsto vd sd)) (derived ss sd)))          

(rule (dcall 11 12))
(rule (pointsto 11 #b001))
(rule (pointsto 12 #b010))

(query (derived #b001 #b010))
```

Comment: The syntax seems to be wrong.
Why do you write

       pointsto(vs ss)

instead of

      (pointsto vs ss)

?

Comment: Sorry. A typo. corrected now. But still no results show.

Comment: By running on local Z3 instead of rise4fun, I found "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_cast: std::bad_cast"

Answer (score 2):

This example exposes a few things. I will try to go through these.

1. The query returns "sat" or "unsat". In the "sat" case there is a set of tuples corresponding to the free variables in the query such that the query is derivable. To print these tuples you can specify ":print-answer true" as an option.
2. Your particular query does not contain any free variables, so there are no tuples to print.
3. I added another example that contains free variables and Z3 prints a solution.
4. The datalog engine doesn't really support infinite domains. You should use relations over Booleans, bit-vectors or finite domain values (a special sort used for programs entered in datalog format). I have changed your example to use bit-vectors.

```html
(set-option :fixedpoint.engine datalog)
(define-sort site () (_ BitVec 3))
(define-sort Loc () (_ BitVec 8))

(declare-rel pointsto (Loc site))
(declare-rel dcall (Loc Loc))
(declare-rel derived (site site))

(declare-var vs Loc)
(declare-var vd Loc)
(declare-var ss site)
(declare-var sd site)

;;;;; definition of derived ;;
(rule (=> (and (dcall vs vd) (pointsto vs ss) (pointsto vd sd)) (derived ss sd)))          

(rule (dcall (_ bv11 8) (_ bv12 8)))
(rule (pointsto (_ bv11 8) #b001))
(rule (pointsto (_ bv12 8) #b010))

(query (derived #b001 #b010) 
   :print-answer true)

(query (derived #b001 ss) 
   :print-answer true)
```